# parsing nsmutabledictionary brings an empty uitable. what am i missing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist

i am trying to show display all the words in key "word" from a plist on a remote server. the plist is as follows:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>word</key>
    <string>wordhere</string>
    <key>definition</key>
    <string>definition Here</string>
    <key>partOfSpeech</key>
    <string>part of speech here</string>
    <key>crossReference</key>
    <string>cross reference here</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>word</key>
    <string>wordhere2</string>
    <key>definition</key>
    <string>definition here2</string>
    <key>partOfSPeech</key>
    <string>part of speech here2</string>
    <key>crossReference</key>
    <string>cross reference here2</string>
</dict>
```

**Update** can ignore the plist. i rewrote it so its a hard coded array. still same error though.
i've visited the url of the plist, so i know that works. but here's my code. for some reason it's not pulling into my uitable when i run. maybe im missing something. im just wanting the key: word to populate to form the uitable list. any help would be appreciated :D **updated**

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Dictionary";
 [myArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"word1", @"word", @"Definition1", @"definition", @"Part of speech1", @"partOfSpeech", @"cross Reference1", @"crossReference", nil]];
```

and here's my UITableViewCell

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            ;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"word"];
```

Comment: Show the code you use to populate the table view cells.

Comment: The code you posted to get the array makes no sense at all. Verify `myArray` has the content you expect it to have. And no one can answer your question because you don't show any code for showing a value in a table.

Comment: ok. did that. its building and running with no errors, but the list is empty. hmm. ill update my code and show you how i tried to write a hard coded array. still comes up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `myArray` is an array of dictionaries, then this *should* work:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: after doing that, im getting "no known instance method for selector 'objectWithKey'. suggestions?

Comment: @GeoffHill That was a typo; it should be `objectForKey:`.

Comment: got it. i forgot to change "key" to "word" thanks! youre awesome.